# How event handler really works?

Tags: javafx-8

I  am new to Java and as i was going through event handling I was unable to understand how exactly event handler works. I will try my best to explain my question. Suppose I have the following code that simply launch JavaFX application and draws a line and a button on stage:

```
public class Understanding extends Application
{

    Linepane lpane = new Linepane();


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Application.launch(args);


    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception 
    {


        Button bt = new Button("change");
        stage.setTitle("Understand");
        BorderPane bpane = new BorderPane();
        bpane.setBottom(bt);
        bpane.setCenter(lpane);
        bt.setOnAction(new Handler());
        Scene scene = new Scene(bpane, 300, 300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }
    public class Handler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>
    {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {

            lpane.change();

        }

    }
}

public class Linepane extends StackPane
{
    Line line = new Line(1,1,50,50);

    public Linepane()
    {

        this.getChildren().add(line);
    }

    public void change()
    {
        line.setEndX(100);
        line.setEndY(100);
    }
}
```

All this program does is draw a line and change the length of the line on clicking the button change but how is that possible once the program is run start method is invoked and the code runs from the first line to last line which is showing the stage (`stage.show()`) and how is it able to change the length of line does the whole program run again when the button is clicked or the program just stays on the line that says what to do when the button is clicked and runs that part of code as soon as the  button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

after `Application.launch(args)` a JavaFX application thread is build. Within this application thread an object of type Understanding (and a Stage) will be created. After creation done Understand#start(..) will be called and processed until to stage.show().

After the call of stage.show() the JavaFX application thread still is running and processes users input events. When user clicks on Button `bt` the JavaFX application thread processes this event and calls the handle method of the Handler object.

Your program will not be run and run again up to `stage.show()`, only the JavaFX application thread runs again and again and listens to events. For each matching event it calls matching methods of your application.

for more details: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html